# Send message to a specified user

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a bot and I want it to send a private message to a specified user.

For example:

```
!message @user Welcome to the server!
```

This would send "Welcome to the server!" to @user.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the error?

Comment: I've tried `client.author.get(user).send("Welcome to the server!")`. The error message is `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'`

Comment: Have you created a listener for the message event? Add all the code that is relevant to your original post.

Comment: Clients don't have an author, so I assume that's a message. Message authors are already a user, so you don't need to get an author. And users (such as "author") have a dmChannel member which you can use to send messages to. I assume you want to do something like `message.author.dmChannel.send('Welcome to the server!');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.js has a property called message#mentions with this you can do

```
var user = message.mentions.users.first();
```

This returns either `undefined` if no user was mentioned or the `UserResovleable` where yo then can

```
user.send("Welcome to the server!");
// or for example
console.log(user.id);
```